# OpenCV equivalent for thresholding in MATLAB

Tags: c++, image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I want to implement this MATLAB statement in OpenCV C++:

```
 bwImgLabeled(bwImgLabeled > 0) = 1;
```

As far as I understand from then OpenCV docs,  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold, 
I need to do:

```
cv::threshold(dst, dst, 0, 1, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

Am I correct here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct.  What the MATLAB code is doing is that it searches for any pixels that are non-zero and sets them to 1.

Recall the definition of [`cv::threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold):

```
double threshold(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, 
                 double thresh, double maxval, int type)
```

So the first two inputs are the source and destination images, where in your case, you want to take the destination image and mutate it to contain the final image.  `thresh = 0` and `maxval = 1`, with `type=CV_THRESH_BINARY`.  Recall when using the `CV_THRESH_BINARY`, the following relationship occurs:

[image]
<sub>(source: [opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/_images/math/21dfc802899546a3a9a51794d241330e6377f032.png))</sub>

Therefore, if you specify `thresh` to be 0, `maxval` to be 1, you are effectively doing what the MATLAB code is doing.  Any pixels that are greater than `thresh=0`, which are essentially non-zero, you set those intensities to 1.  I'm assuming you want the input and output images to be **floating-point**, so make sure the image is of a compatible type, such as `CV_32FC1`, or `CV_32FC3`, and so on.